# Using var into an insert update request does not work

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-insert

I try to insert values into a table using following request :

```
INSERT IGNORE itemmaster
(
SKU,
product_id
)
SELECT
@massimport_SKU := main.SKU,
@massimport_product_id := prd.entity_id
FROM itemmaster AS main
INNER JOIN product_entity AS prd ON prd.sku = main.SKU
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = @massimport_product_id
```

SKU is a unique key. 
The problem is the value of product_id is always the same id. If I only execute the select, product_id are different but after insert, only one value in product_id column. I think this is a problem with var `@massimport_product_id` cause if I use`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = prd.entity_id` instead the request work perfectly.

But cause it's an automatic generated request who work well in all other case, I hope somebody coul me explain why this append.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use session variables, that can't work.

Use this:

```
INSERT IGNORE itemmaster( SKU, product_id )
SELECT main.SKU, prd.entity_id
FROM itemmaster AS main
INNER JOIN product_entity AS prd ON prd.sku = main.SKU
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = prd.entity_id
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592187/1

However INNER JOIN in this query always returns records (values of SKU column), that already exist in `itemmaster` table, so INSERT is useles in this case, and the same can be done simpler, using multitable update:

```
UPDATE itemmaster main
JOIN product_entity AS prd ON prd.sku = main.SKU
SET main.product_id = prd.entity_id;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/762eb4/1